# Python Mock: Raising Error for function of Mocked Class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

I'm trying to test some code that create or changes directories and files based on some inputs. My issue is raising exceptions when a method of a mocked object is called. For example, say I have some code:

```
def create_if_not_exists(dest):
    dir = os.path.dirname(dest)
    if not dir:
        # create if it doesn't exist
        try:
           os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest))
        except OSError:
           pass # Nevermind what goes here, it's unimportant to the question
```

My unit test follows these ideas:

- `os.path.dirname()` returns `None` means that the path not exists
- `os.makedirs()` raises an `OSError` Exception

```
@patch('my.package.os')
def test_create_dir_if_not_exists(self, mock_os):
    # dirname return None means that the path not exists
    mock_os.path.dirname.return_value = None
    # by following instruction I want to raise an OSError Exception
    mock_os.makedirs.raiseError.side_effect = OSError()

    with self.assertRaises(OSError)
        create_if_not_exists('test')
```

This setup returns `AssertionError: OSError not raised` but my understanding is it should raise the error when the `makedirs` call is made in the actual (non-test) method. Is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following patch in the test file:

```
@patch('my.package.os.path.dirname')
@patch('my.package.os.makedirs')
def test_create_dir_if_not_exists(self, mock_os_makedirs, mock_os_path_dirname):
    mock_os_path_dirname.return_value = None
    # mock_os.makedirs.raiseError.side_effect = OSError() <--- REMOVE raiseError
    mock_os_makedirs.side_effect = OSError()

    with self.assertRaises(OSError)
        create_if_not_exists('test')
```

Furthermore your function `create_if_not_exists()` must not to catch the `OSError` exception; so your `create_if_not_exists()` function must be modified as followed:

```
import os

def create_if_not_exists(dest):
    dir = os.path.dirname(dest)
    if not dir:
        # create if it doesn't exist
        #try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest))
        #except OSError:
        #   pass # Nevermind what goes here, it's unimportant to the question
```

otherwise the test fails.

#### Also your test was good

In your test the only problem was the instruction:

```
mock_os.makedirs.raiseError.side_effect = OSError()
```

So an other solution for your test is:

- remove the `try-except OSError` in your production code
- change your test code as following:

```
@patch('my.package.os')
def test_create_dir_if_not_exists(self, mock_os):
    mock_os.path.dirname.return_value = None
    #mock_os.makedirs.raiseError.side_effect = OSError() <--- REMOVE raiseError
    mock_os.makedirs.side_effect = OSError()

    with self.assertRaises(OSError):
        create_if_not_exists('test')
```

Comment: Thanks. It appears that using the syntax of patching the library and then making return values for individual methods that I was using is incorrect (or I had set it up incorrectly). After more closely inspecting the values from the mocks I found it worked better. Thank you!

Comment: @wyt Sorry but from your comment I don't understand if you have changed the patch() as I have suggested in the answer or you have made some other changes to your test code.. Could you explain better your modifications?

Comment: yes I changed the `patch()` as you suggested. My understanding was that you could patch a library (eg `@patch('my.package.os)`) and then set individual return values for each method of that library. As was in my original question: `mock_os.path.dirname.return_value = None`. It appears from my testing that that is not the case. Each method must be patched individually.

Comment: Yes you are right. Now I have understood your previous comment.

Comment: @wyt I don't know if you would like to know more details about your question, but however I have updated my answer with some useful details. I have tested all my code this time. When I wrote the first time the answer I didn't test it.